# jqueryui select menu trigger change to re-style item inside selector span

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an issue where I wish to re-style an item inside a selectmenu dropdown list when a new item is dynamically changed by other javascript.

The `change` event works when I pick the item from the dropdown list by clicking a desired option, but not when I do so via javascript (see last 2 lines).
The text value changes from "Black" to "White", but the color square still shows the old css.

```
$("#original-native-dropdown")
.selectmenu({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        var widget = $(this).selectmenu("widget");
        // pass in style from a <span> inside the native <option> tags used in the selectmenu
        const span = $('<span id="' + this.id + 'selected" class="color-option-selected"> ').html("&nbsp;").appendTo(widget);
        const styleString = $(this).parent().find("select > option:first > span:first").data("style");
        span.attr("style", styleString);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        // works when the user clicks an item in the selection dropdown but not from the outside.
        $("#" + this.id + 'selected').parent().children(":last").attr("style", ui.item.element.children(":first").data("style"));
    }
})
.selectmenu("menuWidget")
.addClass("ui-menu-icons color-option");

$("#original-native-dropdown").val("White");
$("#original-native-dropdown").selectmenu("refresh").trigger("selectmenuchange");
```

[image: The color square changes only when user clicks.]
The color square changes only when user clicks.

[image: The color square is not restyled when selection is changed via javascript.]
The color square is not restyled when selection is changed via javascript.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can, it will take a while.